# How to deal with character underscore when using font 'libre barcode 39 extended text' in g-sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a text a_bcde which is transformed to a barcode in g-sheets using font libre barcode 39 extended text.

Note: I found 'only' three barcode fonts (13, 39 and 128) in g-sheet and my scanner only interprets 39.

Problem: when reading the barcode the scanner produces a%Obcde instead of a_bcde.

I was not able to locate anything useful from google on the subject, but [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_39) place dwells on the character set, which seems to be relevant in this case since I fond that  _  corresponds to %O.

Given that I dont know much (=anything) about characters sets and I need the scanner to produce a_bcde when reading a_bcde (and NOT a%Obcde) I have the following question:

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you try using [Libre Barcode 39 Extended Text](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Libre+Barcode+39+Extended+Text) font style instead?

Comment: You can also check out this [article](https://barcodewiz.com/activex-control/user-manual/symbologies/code-39-and-code-39-extended) explaining the difference between code 39 and extended code 39

Comment: @CenturyTuna AGH! Stupid me :-( I am using Libre Barcode 39 Extended Text. I have fixed the title and description. Sorry.

Comment: I don't know anything on the topic either, but could it be that your scanner doesn't implement all of the multicharacter sequences? If you try others in the string, such as `!#%>=}`, what does the scanner produce?

Comment: In line with @Marijn's comment, you could verify if your scanner has some kind of "Extended Mode" that supports the extended version of Code 39

Comment: @Marjin yes you are right! I started looking into it and it turns out I can set the scanner so that it interprets multicharacter sequences. Now it worx! Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct answer was as provided by @Marjin and @Centruy Tuna: set the scanner so that it interprets multicharacter sequences.